# Text to speech conversion in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm trying to integrate text to speech functionality in my iOS app.

For this I'm using `AVSpeechUtterance` and `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice` classes of `AVFoundation` framework.

```
extension String {
    func speech(with pronunciation: String) {
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(attributedString: NSAttributedString(string: self, attributes: [.accessibilitySpeechIPANotation : pronunciation]))
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
        let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            synth.speak(utterance)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is with the pronunciation of **wind** word as verb and noun, i.e.

1. wind as a **verb** is pronounced: **waɪnd**
2. and wind as a **noun** is pronounced: **wɪnd**

The above pronunciation strings follow the **International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA)**.

But, I'm not getting the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an IPA translation of a specific spelling, I suggest to use the iOS feature located at:

- `Settings > General > Accessibility > Speech > Pronunciations` *(iOS 12)*.
- `Settings > Accessibility > Spoken Content > Pronunciations` *(iOS 13)*

Once you choose the desired result, you can [use it in your code](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#speech-synthesis) to be vocalized by the speech synthesizer.

**EDIT**

> this solution also doesn't work for me.

I'm quite surprised by your comment because when I follow every steps of the provided link, I get the code snippet hereunder:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let pronunciationKey = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute)

//        let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "blablablaNOUN",
//                                                attributes: [pronunciationKey: "ˈwɪnd"])
    let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "blablablaVERB",
                                            attributes: [pronunciationKey: "ˈwa͡ɪnd"])
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(attributedString: attrStr)

        let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)
}
```

... and when I launch this blank app **after changing the `iPhone Language`** in the `Settings - General - Language & Region` menu, I get the correct pronunciations for the verb and the noun.

Copy-paste the code snippet hereabove and test it by yourself.

Comment: This works almost great. I'm trying to correct the pronunciation of my `accessibilityAttributedLabel`, problem is that I have **two** strings that I need to correct. My design doesn't allow me to use a single string. When I read an individual `accessibilityAttributedLabel` it works correct. However if I concatenate the attributedStrings then it defaults back to reading the original words without correct pronunciation. Have you solved this?

Comment: @Honey: I suggest to open a new topic about your question including code snippet that shows the way you handle the problem, please. It's the best way to provide an appropriate answer that will be available for the greatest number of interested people.  ;o)