# Swift Text-To-Speech - pronunciation

Tags: swift, text-to-speech, avspeechutterance

how I can set pronunciation for 1 word in `AVSpeechUtterance`? for example - `read [ri:d], read [red], read [red]` spelled the same but pronounced differently

```
AVSpeechUtterance(string: "read") // in second form, how?
```

Comment: i need only 1 word, i set something like phonetic transcription

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/56027799/341994. I really shouldn’t have answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an attributed string with International Phonetic Alphabet pronunciation attached by way of the AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute key.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechutterance/1648776-init

Comment: https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#speech-synthesis is also a good source of information with code snippets and illustrations.